# How to add a text file as resource in VC++ 2005?

Tags: visual-c++, resources

I want to add a text file as resource in VC++ 2005. I am not able to find text as option in resource template.

Also once added how can I refer to that file while programming?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's pretty simple: In your solution, switch to resource view, right click on your RC file, select "Add Resource", click on "Import", select "All files" then open the file you want. You're prompted to type in a custom resource type. Enter "TEXT" for example.

You can now load your custom resource like this:

```
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_TEXT1), _T("TEXT"));
DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), hRes);
HGLOBAL hGlob = LoadResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), hRes);
const BYTE* pData = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(::LockResource(hGlob));
```

You don't need to unlock or free the resource, so this code can be used exactly as written without any additional calls.  The resource will be freed when your program exits.

Comment: AfxGetResourceHandle is only available in MFC . Any idea which API I can use in win32?

I am creating an exe and all the resources are in that exe.

Comment: Use GetModuleHandle(NULL). Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: GetModuleHandle(NULL) works for EXE resources, but the DLL module handle should be provided for resources located therein. And not to forget to null terminate the string given possible garbage characters that follow in the glob.